# How to write a dynamic equation that depends on a constant

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write an equation that depends on a constant (number of levels). As shown below, if I have 2 levels, the if statements will refer to L1 and L2.

QUESTIONS:

1. How can I modify the code to **reflect x number of levels**? x could be any integers (usually from 2-12).
2. How can I rewrite the code **without the for loops**?

Thanks so much for your help!

**For example (for 2 levels):**

## Look-up table

```
L1_var <- c("Price", "Price", "Price", "Price")
L1_val <- c("AO", "AO", "Premium", "Premium")

L2_var <- c("Type", "Type", "Form", "Form")
L2_val <- c("Diet", "Regular", "Bottle", "Can")

tbl <- data.frame(L1_var, L1_val, L2_var, L2_val)
```

## Dataset

```
Price <- c("Premium", "AO", "AO")
Type  <- c("Diet", "Regular", "Diet")
Form  <- c("Bottle", "Bottle", "Can")

df <- data.frame(Price, Type, Form)
```

## For num_level = 2

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(tbl)) {
    if (df[i, tbl$L1_var[j]] == tbl$L1_val[j] & 
        df[i, tbl$L2_var[j]] == tbl$L2_val[j]) {
      df[i, "L1"] <- paste0(tbl$L1_var[j], ": ", tbl$L1_val[j])
      df[i, "L2"] <- paste0(tbl$L2_var[j], ": ", tbl$L2_val[j])
    }
  }
}
```

If I have 3 number of levels in df, I want the code to be:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(tbl)) {
    if (df[i, tbl$L1_var[j]] == tbl$L1_val[j] & 
        df[i, tbl$L2_var[j]] == tbl$L2_val[j] &
        df[i, tbl$L3_var[j]] == tbl$L3_val[j] ) {
       
      df[i, "L1"] <- paste0(tbl$L1_var[j], ": ", tbl$L1_val[j])
      df[i, "L2"] <- paste0(tbl$L2_var[j], ": ", tbl$L2_val[j])
      df[i, "L3"] <- paste0(tbl$L3_var[j], ": ", tbl$L3_val[j])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach to the problem, making heavy use of `purrr` and `dplyr`. It should work for any number of variables in `tbl`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

tbl %>%
  pmap(function(...) {
    args <- c(...)
    vars <- args[seq(1, length(args), 2)] %>%
      set_names(NULL)
    values <- args[seq(2, length(args), 2)] %>%
      set_names(vars)
    df %>%
      filter(across(vars, ~ . == values[cur_column()])) %>%
      mutate(across(.cols = vars,
                    .fns = ~ sprintf("%s: %s", cur_column(), .),
                    .names = "L{which(vars ==.col)}"))
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()
```